# How to define an external source folder in .pydevproject?

Tags: pydev

Are there any examples of how to add an external source directory to the pythonpath in the .pydevproject file?  The pydev UI appears to require string substitution variables for this, which I have not been able to get working.

Thanks!

-Travis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them as **External Libs**.

Project Properties > Pydev - PYTHONPATH > External Libraries > Add Source Folder

[image: External Libs]

[image: Select the external source folder]

Comment: Maybe I am just not understanding what "add external source folder" actually means.  The solution you propose is the first thing I tried, but the only folders the UI allows me to add are folders that exist inside my project.  I want to add a source folder to my pythonpath that is outside of the eclipse project I'm working in.  Since configuring this in the UI doesn't appear to work, I'm happy to edit my .pydevproject file directly to set this up.  But I need an example.

Comment: Got it working.  (I think the UI needs improvement here.)  My mistake was that I was using the UI under the "Source Folders" tab to add an external source folder, instead of the UI under "External Libraries" tab.

Comment: Hi Travis, 
My environment: PyDev 2.6  + Ubuntu 12.04 + Eclipse 3.8

In the external libraries tab, I can actually select the source folder "outside" of my project. Please see my updated screenshot.

Anyway, Glad to see it's solved.  :)

Comment: Hello, I managed to follow Cody's solution, but can I go further ? I mean to edit files in the Eclipse's Editor view ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Laurent, I don't think it make sense to modify codes in  "external" library.  If you want to modify it, you should put them into your "internal" source folder. right ?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's the .pydevproject code that gets this working:

```
<pydev_pathproperty name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATH">
    <path>/home/travis/git/apollo/util/src/java</path>
    ...
</pydev_pathproperty>
```