# How to add external Java libraries' folder to Jython project in PyDev?

Tags: jar, import, pydev, jython

I am completely new to Python/Jython/PyDev.

I just tried to add a folder containing JARs as an External Source Folder to my Jython project as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12583946/2018047

Unfortunately, imports only resolved when adding the JARs individually (instead of their containing folder).

Do I have to add something like __init__.py files to those directories to make it work on a per folder basis? How are the init files structured?